# UIWebView new window request isn't working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a code (objective-c) that should open a new window (viewcontroller) when a link with a certain string in a uiwebview is clicked. But it doesn't work.

Here's the code from the .m file:

```
-(BOOL)webView2:(UIWebView*)webView2 shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSURL *url = request.URL;
    NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;

    //Check if special link
    if ( [ urlString isEqualToString: @"http://google.com/" ] ) {
        //Here present the new view controller
        ViewController *ViewController8 = [[ViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:ViewController8 animated:YES completion:nil];

        return NO;
    }

    return YES;

}
```

The new viewcontroller subclass name is: ViewController8 and the UIWebView subclass is: webView2

Here's the code from the .h file:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface ViewController8 : UIViewController

    @end

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController{
        IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
        IBOutlet UIButton *openMenu;
        int draw1;
    }
    - (IBAction)OpenMenu:(id)sender;

    @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;


    @end
```

How do I fix it so a new window (viewcontroller) is opened when a link with a certain string in a uiwebview is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure about your method signature for the shouldStartLoadWithRequest delegate method?

Did you really override the default method to have it call:

-(BOOL)webView2:(UIWebView*)webView2 shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType

???

Or should you instead be replacing "webview2" with "webView" there?

Even if you did, the naming convention would be very confusing.

The default implementation is for a class named "UIWebView", but the delegate method references "webView".

But in your case, you have a class called "webView2", and you're calling a delegate method that should be named:

-(BOOL)webView2:(webView2 *)webView2 shouldStartLoadWithRequest...

Doesn't look right at all.

Somehow I think the problem is mixed up in there. But maybe I'm wrong. So the second question is, have you set a breakpoint at the beginning of your shouldStartLoadWithRequest method to see if it ever gets called?

When you say it "doesn't work", what does that mean? How far does it get?

If it actually gets to the method, then perhaps the problem is that the URL it contains is formatted differently than the string you're looking for. Perhaps the trailing '/' isn't there or "www." **is** there.

Edit:

I would try something like this:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

NSRange rangeOfGoogle = [request.URL.absoluteString rangeOfString:@"google.com"];

//Check if special link
if (rangeOfGoogle.location != NSNotFound) {
    //Here present the new view controller
    ViewController8 *viewController = [[ViewController8 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    return NO;
    }

    return YES;

}
```

Comment: How can i re-code it so it will work the way I want it

Comment: I got the error - property url not found on object of type NSUrlRquest -  on line -
    NSRange rangeOfGoogle = [request.url.absoluteString rangeOfString:@"google.com"];

Comment: Oops, "url" should have been capitalized. Fixed it in the sample code.

Comment: You said you created a subclass of UIViewController called ViewController8. Did you really subclass it, or did you mean you have an instance of UIViewController called ViewController8? Also looks like you have a typo and replaced the '8' with a '0'.

Comment: It's the custom class that's named ViewController0 (0 isn't an error by the way)

Comment: That error should be unrelated to the code snippets above. So you have a class file "ViewController.m" that references a class called "ViewController0"? Do each of your UIViewController subclasses have their own files, or are they all declared in one file?

Comment: they're both declared in one file, ViewController8 and 0. It is related to the code above because I got that error when I used it

Comment: I did fix one error in the code sample. The initialization of viewController was wrong. The line should be:
ViewController8 *viewController = [[ViewController8 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
But the error you're seeing is related to the usage of the "ViewController0" class, and that isn't referenced in the code snippets above.

Comment: I renamed ViewController8 to ViewController0

Comment: And changed the custom class to ViewController0

Comment: Okay, so if you comment out the line that initializes the instance of ViewController0 and the one that presents it, does the error go away?

Comment: This part?  - **ViewController8 *viewController = [[ViewController8 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];**

Comment: Yes. Comment out those lines and see if it builds.

Comment: Yes, it does but i won't open a new window when I press the google.com link

Comment: Of course, but that confirms that the problem is in those two lines.

What do those lines look like in your code now?

Comment: **//ViewController8 *viewController = [[ViewController8 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];  //[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];**

Comment: That shouldn't be your current code if you renamed "ViewController8" to "ViewController0".

Comment: Sorry, i meant  
//ViewController0 *viewController = [[ViewController0 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; //[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Then that means you declared ViewController0 in your header file but never provided a implementation for it, which presumably should have been in the same source file as your "ViewController" subclass.

Comment: I implementated ViewController0, i don't receive errors anymore but it still does't work when I press the link (http://google.com/)

Comment: Okay, good. So back to my original comment, set a breakpoint at the beginning of shouldStartLoadWithRequest to see if it ever gets called. And make sure you have set the delegate of the webview to the object that this delegate method is implemented in.

Comment: I added a breakpoint but how do I make sure the delegate is set (and those things)

Comment: Somewhere in the setup of the webview call:

webView.delegate = self; (or whatever object you implemented shouldStartLoadWithRequest in)

Comment: Would help to see the entirety of your source file where shouldStartLoadWithRequest is defined, which is presumably the object you want to be your webViewDelegate.

Comment: Do you want me to post the entire .h/.m file?

Comment: It would help to figure out what the remaining problem is.

Comment: the remaining issue is that the new window (view controller with webview) doesn't open when I press a link with the strong "http://google.com/"

Comment: The important parts to make that happen are: 1) receive the callback that asks if we should load the page, 2) create the new view controller, 3) display the new view controller. One of those steps isn't happening. Easiest way to figure it out is to start with number 1, and see if your shouldStartLoadWithRequest is getting called, using a breakpoint. If it's not, most likely, the delegate isn't being set. The delegate could be set in the Interface Builder, or it could be set programmatically, likely when the view is loaded.

Comment: Can you fix my code to do so? I am a bit confused and I am a beginner at objective-c

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what you need to change without knowing how your project is put together. If you have an IBOutlet for the WebView defined in the header of the view controller that you are using as the web view's delegate, then somewhere in the setup of the view controller, like in viewDidLoad, should be a line like, "self.webview.delegate = self".

Answer (score 0):

I  hope this will work for you

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView2 shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {

NSURL *url = request.URL;
NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;

//Check if special link
if ( [ urlString isEqualToString: @"http://google.com/" ] ) {

    //Here present the new view controller

    ViewController *ViewController8 = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:ViewController8 animated:YES completion:nil];

    return NO;
}

}

return YES;

}
```

it works for me.